# why is this probability defined on sample space, not sigma algebra

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory

[image]

**I've seen lots of probability that is defined on sigma-algebra, and this capture form makes sense as well. My question is, why is this not defined on sigma-algebra, if so, what does it suppose to look like when it is defined on sigma-algebra**

Comment: You can check that $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @GrafZahl Thank you for your reply. Yes, but $\rho$ is defined on $\Omega$, which is not. Why is that

Comment: $\rho$ is not a measure, it is a density function. You are defining $\mathbb{P}$ via $\rho$.

Comment: The terminology is a little confusing here. Usually *density functions* are *integrated* which yields a measure or distribution, while *mass functions* are summed. Anyway here the *measure* $\mathbb{P}$ is defined on $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$, so the measure is defined on a sigma algebra. The measure is defined in terms of the mass function $\rho$ which is defined on the sample space itself.

Comment: Does this have to be a discrete distribution bc of “countable” and “power set”? If so why wouldn’t they say probability mass function.

Comment: @Jellyfish Probability mass function would actually be the commonly used terminology for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For countable sample space it is actually unnecessary to use a sigma-algebra. The problems arise in situations where the sample space is not countable anymore. A nice example is the infinite coin toss with $\Omega=\{0,1\}^N$. Using the power set, it is actually impossible to define a probability density function that fulfills the Kolmogoroff Axioms.

For your specific definition it would be equivalent to have the following:

Let $\Omega$ be countable. Any function $\rho:\Omega\rightarrow[0,1]$ with $$\sum_{\omega\in\Omega}\rho(\omega)=1$$
induces a probability measure $\mathbb P$, where $\mathbb P$ is defined for arbitrary $A\subseteq\Omega$ via
$$\mathbb P(A):=\sum_{\omega\in A}\rho(\omega)$$

If you would want to put special emphasis on the fact that even in the countable or finite case one can use other sigma-algebras than just the power set, you would introduce $\rho$ as a function from the sigma-Algebra $\mathcal F$ to $[0,1]$, the rest stays as above, exept now $A\in\mathcal F$ is necessary and $\mathbb P(A)$ for general $A\subset\Omega$ is not defined.

There are a few neat examples of sigma-Algebras (they work for non-countable sample space, too):

- trivial sigma-Algebra $\mathcal F=\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$
- $\mathcal F=\{\emptyset, A, A^c, \Omega\}$

This sort of extended definition is however more useful for discrete stochastic processes like Martingales and in particular if you want to construct random variables using conditional expectation.

In that sense, the definition of the original post is not very nice. It is indeed confusing.